# How are preprocessors linked to different target frameworks?

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-standard

I'm following along with [a talk by Immo Landwerth](https://youtu.be/hLFyycJVo0I?t=1024), in a .NET standard project, I saw him switching between projects (which are not typically projects under the solution) from the top left drop-down menu, here is a gif: https://image.ibb.co/mmjoHU/pre.gif

To reproduce the same thing I created a class library in .NET Framework to see the goings, but the project failed to load (with a modified csproj file to be the same as the demo's csproj), then I created a .NET standard library and modified the .csproj file to this (the same as [the demo's csproj](https://github.com/terrajobst/dnc18-demo2/blob/step-1/Gps/Gps.csproj)):

```
<Project Sdk="MSBuild.Sdk.Extras">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.4;net461;uap10.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.ValueTuple" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <Reference Include="System.Device" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

I could see the three target frameworks:netstandard1.4;net461;uap10.0. but really couldn't understand how they got mapped to the preprocessors: NET461, WINDOWS_UWP. which work on the Immo's project, but didn't work with my modified .NET standard library and the three targets didn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like conditional compilation symbols with linked .cs files to me.

In the Properties > Build tab, you should see a textbox labelled "Conditional compilation symbols". Any strings you put in this textbox can be used to conditionally execute code with `#if` and `#elif`. There are also symbols that the build system is already aware of (some are listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-multitarget)).

[image: Build tab]

I'm assuming these projects also share the same .cs files, which explains the #if/#elif/#else conditions "flipping" within the same file (when you add a file to a project, choose add it as a link to an existing file, then a copy is not made).

[image: Add as link]

I have done this exact thing on multiple projects for different configurations and the behavior matches the .gif you posted.

Comment: I checked for conditional compilation symbols in the demo project, but it's empty

Comment: @mshwf This page says there are some the build system is aware of (about halfway down the page, search for NET461). It doesn't mention WINDOWS_UWP, but is possible that is a built in symbol as well (never really worked with UWP). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/libraries#how-to-multitarget

Comment: For example, another one that is built in, is DEBUG (i.e. `#if DEBUG`)